# Oracle APEX 21.1 - Mobile Optimization (Stretch Buttons & Radio Groups)

Tags: oracle-apex

I am in the process of trying to apply the Universal Theme Responsive Grid classes to my application to make the application look better on mobile. I am targeting anything < 639px as mobile (X Small or `.col-xs-` css class). The two issues I am trying to resolve are:

1. Buttons: how do I dynamically change buttons to go from APEX default width to 'Stretch' (100% width) when this media breakpoint is reached? The only native settings I see are to have 'Stretch' on or off
2. Radio Groups: it looks like radio groups are set to 50% width for anything less than 640px. How would I keep the default 100% width or even dynamically change them to pills for mobile?

I found this Oracle video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPWuNrKlBFw), and tried to install the sample app, but was throwing errors when I tried to install.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add this class "t-Button--stretch" to the Button, when you want it to be stretched.
2. Add this inline CSS to the Page to give the Radio groups 100% width always.

   `.apex-item-option { width: 100% !important;}`

Use @media Query to use them for desired Screen size.